# How to RegEx match ()'s at the end of a word

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex `@""` to match two brackets `()` at the end of a word.

Tried doing `\w*()\b` but didn't work.

So I need to match something like this: `"Hello, world test(test) testing"`.

I just need it to match the `test(word)` there.

Comment: `/[(].*[)]/g` use this. and check this in https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a space after the last parenthesis, using a word boundary will not get a match as there is no word boundary between `)` and a space.

Note that using `\w*` will optionally repeat word characters and could possibly also match just `()`

You might use:

```
\w+\((?:\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)?\)
```

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?:` Non capture group
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

  - `(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching `,` and 1+ word characters
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8jpd1/1)

Comment: @"\w+\(\w*\)(?!\S)" doesn't work at all but @"\w+\(\w*\)" works but I also want the whitespace to work for example "hello(a) hello(a)". And I also need it to detect more params like "test(a, b)" because this is for a syntax highlighter for lua. https://gyazo.com/43521715663bfb24a3e668dd18b81e54

Comment: @IvanoVladimirSetiawan LIke this? https://regex101.com/r/z2iGmj/1

Comment: yes like that but for some reason my syntax highlighter dooesn't work

Comment: well now test(a, b) works but still for some reason the whitespace just doesn't work I think it's the color code I wrote but I'm not sure. https://gyazo.com/dbac4542539f12eb731d631a79d1247b

Answer (score 0):

`(` and `)` are special characters for grouping. So you must escape them to match literal parentheses. You also need to put something inside the parentheses to match the word there

```
\w*\(\w*\)\b
```

Comment: it works if I do like "testing(test)aaaa but not testing(test) aaaa" the whitespace doesn't allow the regex to work for some reason. Also I want it to also detect like "testing(a, b)" too. This is a syntax highlighting for lua.

Comment: @IvanoVladimirSetiawan using regex for syntax highlight is a bad idea. You need a real tokenizer for that job, otherwise it'll fail in lots of cases

Comment: I have the regex on a seperate dll so it doesn't lag even on ten's and thousand lines

Comment: it has nothing to do with lagging. Who said about that? It's the correctness of the parsing. Using a regex and it may have issues in many cases like code inside comments or many other corner cases

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`/[^\s]+[(].*[)]/g` use this. and check this in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

I add this expression and you give string. my expression is highlighted you needed string.